# Vertical menu bootstrap and angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create vertical menu like this [site](http://themicon.co/theme/angle/v1.6/#/app/dashboard) . the thing i'm looking for is : when menu is collapse sub menus open with hover and when menu is open , sub menus open below the links .

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/) , what i've done is : i can open the menu after click the button .
sub menu is working (last one) **but** i don't want to open submenu when menu is collapsed .

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.noneStyle = false;
    $scope.bodyCon = false;
    $scope.sasd = "asd";


    //Toggle the styles
    $scope.toggleStyle = function () {
        //If they are true, they will become false 
        //and false will become true
        $scope.bodyCon = !$scope.bodyCon;
        $scope.noneStyle = !$scope.noneStyle;
    }


});
```

***UPDATE***

**menu with submenu :**

[image]

**submenu open with hover**
[image: enter link description here]

that's what i want !!
thx in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: sure,please check my link http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0RR5C65 , ther is a sidebar menu with sub links , when you click on the button and close the menu, sub menus open with hover , that's what i want

Comment: let me know, if i'm not clear yet to put picture from what i want

Comment: So you open the menu - click a submenu item (which re-directs you to another page) - close menu and you want the sub-menu to remain the active-link in the menu, is that correct?

Comment: No, wait a little bit , i'm gonna update my question

Comment: i've udpdate it, please check it out

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/zqdmny41/8/

Comment: I voted to close this question as off topic because the code and examples are on third party sites which can go dead tomorrow making this whole question useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/4/

Remove the collapse class from your sub menu list and use ng-mouseenter on the menu and ng-mouseleave on the aside tag.

```
<aside class="rightbar" id="rightMenu" ng-class="{'noneStyle' : noneStyle}"  ng-mouseleave="subMenu = false">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#rightMenu" href="#" ng-mouseover="subMenu = true">Tools<i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></a>
```

Also your div and li tags are all over the place, please structure them correctly. For example, div cannot come in between two li tags.

Comment: thx @Aakash , but this is not what i want , i've udpdate my question, please check it out

Comment: sure, i'll do it, but i dont want to submenu open with hover when menu is open, see my question and links

Comment: man you're the best and creative, but it's not the best and clean way.
thx a lot

Comment: Yeah you'll have to still do a lil bit of fine tuning. Your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS, apply different styles to your submenu when "noneStyle" is toggled, under normal style, your submenu should use `position: absolute; left: --px;` for positioning, and under "noneStyle", it should be `position: static` to force it display with initial style.

and BTW, please do not place `<div>` tag under `<ul>`, it's not a good way to write HTML, I've changed it for you.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.noneStyle = false;
    $scope.bodyCon = false;
    $scope.sasd = "asd";
  

    //Toggle the styles
    $scope.toggleStyle = function () {
        //If they are true, they will become false 
        //and false will become true
        $scope.bodyCon = !$scope.bodyCon;
        $scope.noneStyle = !$scope.noneStyle;
    }
    //add class to search box
    $scope.openSearch = false;
    $scope.searchToggle = function () {

        $scope.openSearch = !$scope.openSearch;

    }

    
});
```

```css
body{
    background:#300F18 !important;
    
}
li{
    
    list-style:none;
}
.rightbar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 200;
}
.rightbar ul li {
   color: #333;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 16px 0 21px;
    /*width: 0;*/
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition:all 0.3s ease;     
        transition:all 0.3s ease;

}
.rightbar ul li:hover {
  background:inherit;
  width:100%;

}
.rightbar ul li a {
    color: #8b8b8b;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 23px;
    padding-right: 54px !important;
    font-size:0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 0.1s ease;
        -o-transition:all 0.1s ease;     
        transition:all 0.1s ease;
}
.accordion-heading .accordion-toggle{
    padding:0;
}



.rightbar ul li a i{
  color: #8b8b8b;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
       transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition:all 0.3s ease;     
        transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion-group{
    border:medium none;
}

.tools-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.tools-menu .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: -140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.tools-menu:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.noneStyle .tools-menu .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: static;
}

.accordion-inner ul li{
    padding:10px 0;
    list-style:none;
}
    .rightbar ul li:hover a,
    .rightbar ul li:hover a i {
        color: #23b7e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    } 
    
.noneStyle a{
    font-size:13px !important;
}
.noneStyle {
     width: 144px;
    z-index: 1000;
     transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition:all 0.3s ease;     
        transition:all 0.3s ease;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default topnavbar">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="toggleStyle()">

                            <em class=" fa fa-navicon">
                            </em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                

         </div>
    
    <aside class="rightbar" id="rightMenu" ng-class="{'noneStyle' : noneStyle}">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/456">Dashboard<i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/123">write<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/963">list<i class="fa fa-list"></i></a></li>
            <li class="tools-menu">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#rightMenu" href="#collapseFour">
                                Tools<i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                            </a>
                  <ul class="submenu">
                    <li> 1</li>
                    <li> 2</li>
                    <li> 3</li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>


       

    </aside>
{{sasd}}
        
</div>
```